# Какой серверный язык выбрать, если я собираюсь стать специалистом по javascript?

Tags: c#, php, java, perl

Сейчас я плотно занялся изучением javascript. И мне этот язык очень нравится. Но не одним фронт-эндом жив человек как говорится. Так что же мне изучать еще в качестве серверного языка? Посоветуйте. PHP? Python? Perl? Java? C#? PHP все ругают, Perl вроде как медленно уходит в прошлое (или я не прав?), Java мне нравится, но у этого языка столько разных ипостасей, что я теряюсь. Может C#?

Comment: Тема старая, но всё же отмечу: JS уже используют не только для красивого веба.   
[Примеров][1], при желании можно найти кучу.  
На личном опыте имел возможность видеть пару самопальных gui standalone приложений.  
Это лишь для справки. В остальном полностью солидарен с @reshu  
Очень советую учить Си(без азов никуда)


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.B4.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.BC.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5

Answer (score 15, accepted):

А я бы посоветовал Вам попробовать все. Если есть какой-то язык, то у него есть поклонники, которые с пеной у рта будут доказывать превосходство своего языка. И здесь только кто кого перекричит. В сегодняшнем мире нельзя быть узким специалистом. Чем больше языков/систем Вы знаете, тем лучше Вы как специалист. Тем осознанней Ваш выбор основного языка для себя. К тому же не следует забывать, что разные задачи иной раз требуют для себя разных языков. А иногда заказчик привередничает.

Один совет - выбирайте системы с открытым кодом. MSDN - это конечно хорошо, но когда Вы можете сами залезть в исходник и все увидеть... К тому же в случае, если сама система имеет открытый код, то к ней очень много решений с открытым кодом, по которым можно учиться.

Answer (score 29):

Если хочется быть совсем специалистом по javascript, почему бы не выбрать **node.js** для сервера? С ним, конечно, требуется определенная сноровка и хорошее понимание того, как он работает, но это, в принципе, справедливо для любого языка/платформы.

А так вы сможете писать на одном языке и клиент, и сервер. А если возьмете для хранения данных Mongo, то и их обработку в БД тоже )

Comment: Или аналогичный вариант - [v8cgi](http://code.google.com/p/v8cgi/)

JavaScript действительно очень мощный и интересный инструмент. Если Вы сейчас ставите перед собой цель изучить JavaScript, то в качестве серверного языка тоже имеет смысл использовать тот же JavaScript.

Comment: @Nofate♦ Вопрос off-topic. Ничего личного, ставлю минус., и попрошу быть вежливым со мной.:)

Answer (score 6):

Нда... JavaScript - это не язык для зарабатывания на хлеб, а просто некий инструмент, который всегда должен быть под рукой. Не советую вам становиться специалистом по JavaScript - это звучит по меньшей мере смешно, если не сказать трагично.

А вообще приличный прогер должен очень хорошо владеть одним из основных языков: C/C++, Java и C#, и разбираться в оставшихся, понимать основные скриптирующие языки: к коим относятся JavaScript, Visual Basic, Perl иже с ними. Обязательно надо владеть SQL!

А каким языком хорошо владеть - это уж ваш выбор, если вам нравится JavaScipt, то Java вам определенно понравится. Все таки синтаксис похож!

Comment: > Нда... JavaScript - это не язык для зарабатывания на хлеб
Разработчики gmail, twitter смотрят на тебя с недоумением.

Comment: Да ладно, даже специалисты по Erlang без работы не остаются. Просто надо понимать, что .Net и Java - это мейнстрим, по нем всегда куча вакансий и они всегда позволят заработать на хлеб.

Comment: @VladimirVG неужели считаете, что в твиттере и gmail главное это скрипты?!

Comment: @Barmaley, скрипты не главное. Но разработка сложных UI на js в наши дни вполне тянет на полноценную ставку программиста. А по мере развития таких вещей как ChromeOS спрос на js будет только расти.

Comment: Кстати,
> прогер должен очень хорошо владеть одним из основных языков: C/C++, Java и C#
> Обязательно надо владеть SQL!

из этого складывается образ enterprise-разработчика или АСУшника. Но есть куча других не менее (а может даже более ;) ) веселых областей и специализаций в программировании.

Comment: Ну конечно есть масса других специализаций, я же писал в контексте вопроса автора не более того. И кстати, что означает теперь АСУшник? :) Сто лет не слышал уже эту аббревиатуру...

Comment: @Barmaley > неужели считаете, что в твиттере и gmail главное это скрипты?!

это то что их отличает. Это важно.

Сейчас вообще всё движется в сторону строго разделения фронтенда (html5 + JS + localstorage) и бэкэнда (REST + AJAX).

Comment: @ValdimirVG - разделение frontend-backend началось не сейчас, а уже давно - очень давно. Вы смотрите узко html5+js - это только браузерная вещь, не спорю браузеры важны, но циклиться на них как-то неразумно. Мейнстрим C/C++ - Java - .NET никуда не делся и не денется

Comment: @Barmaley, индустрия идет по пути упрощения технологий (на мой взгляд - к сожалению), JavaScript для реализации несложной интерфейсной логики используется уже далеко от веб-приложений. Пример: последние тенденции в развитии графических тулкитов для ОС Linux (GTK+ и Qt).

Но с идеей вашего ответа я согласен: программист JavaScript - это как сантехник, который умеет заменить кран, но никогда не видел труб.

Comment: >программист JavaScript - это как сантехник, который умеет заменить кран, но никогда не видел труб.

@northerner, то есть вы не верите в js на серверной стороне?

Comment: Я не про клиент-сервер.

Answer (score 5):

На самом деле всё довольно просто:

1. php - если есть желание быстро и просто научится. Для него щас куча работы как во фрилансе, так и в реале. Во фрилансе это редактирование\натягивание шаблонов\написание модулей ко всяким CMS, а в реале - в любом городе думаю найдётся контора ищущая пхп-кодера.(и не забывает что это самый тормозной и ресурсо-хавающих язык =) )
2. perl, python, ruby - да да, перл умирает ... и умирает ... уже лет 10 как всё умирает. В принципе считаю что языки равноценны. Есть у каждого плюсы, есть минусы. Для каждого найдётся несколько фреймворков и прочего. Но на фрилансе работа для них встреачается не особо часто, зато в Москве всегда найдётся с десяток вакансий. Кстати в отличие от пхп, на этих языках можно писать не только для веба, но и GUI и прочие вещи.
3. C#, Java - нафиг C# !!! Оба языка весьма серьёзные и возможности у них соответствующие. Из двух зол лучше выбирать кросплатформенное(нет, Mono для C# не круто). Опять же во фрилансе работу не найдёшь, затов реале часто втречаются конторы ищущие толковых Java кодеров.
4. а, да ... node.js - круто конечно, но не практично. можно знать в качестве бонуса.

Comment: > и не забывает что это самый тормозной и ресурсо-хавающих язык =) 

Необъективно.

Comment: дело скорее в низком пороге вхождения для желающих "быстро и просто"

Comment: "C#, Java - нафиг C# !!! Оба языка весьма серьёзные и возможности у них соответствующие. Из двух зол лучше выбирать кросплатформенное"
Скажем так! На данный момент людей, использующих операционные системы Microsoft - подавляющее большинство. Кросс-платформенность - это, бесспорно круто, но зачем заказчику эти возможности. Вы скажете - смотрите ваше новое приложение можно использовать на любой платформе, а он ответит - да, это большой плюс, но зачем мне использовать на другой платформе, если у меня стоит Windows Server?А уж в своих то технологиях, я уверен, мелко-мягкие разбираются лучше други

Comment: Вот только не надо в одну кучу сбрасывать юзеров с Виндой и заказчика Windows Server. Сервер и десктоп разные вещи.

Давайте не будем впадать в крайности пытаясь доказать своё мнение. Написанное мной выше более или менее, но отражает суть вещей. И в конечном счёте технологии подбираются под конктетную задачу.

Comment: Случайно забрёл и вижу что @EcSYZ просто не в теме про [возможности php, как языка для GUI][1].  
На нём и ОС какую-то сделали. Это в принципе полноценный ЯП, только быдло-кодеров много.


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Php#.D0.A1.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.B4.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_GUI-.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B9

Answer (score 4):

Может быть мое мнение, конечно, немного субъективно и, возможно, вызовет кучу нелицеприятных высказываний в мою сторону, но, все же, я его выскажу. На мой взгляд лучшая связка для изучения: .NET - C# - MS SQL. Возможности огромные и колоссальная поддержка Microsoft в виде MSDN. А скриптовые языки нужно просто понимать, а не специализироваться в них.

Comment: А еще полезно понимать, что Ruby, JS, Python - это не просто скриптовые языки для бэкапов по cron-у (если уж на то пошло - динамические), но и стоящие за ними фреймворки для разработки приложений.  Ведь ни у кого не повернется назвать фронтенд на ExtJS, равно как и сам ExtJS "скриптиком"?

Comment: Я это к тому, что на _скриптах_ действительно специализироваться не стоит. А вот на разработке _приложений_ на динамическом языке - вполне.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала попробуйте PHP. Сколько его ругают, столько же и хвалят. Чтобы начать на нем что-либо делать, достаточно совсем немного времени потратить на изучение. Полное и глубокое освоение займет примерно одинаково много времени для любого языка.

Кроме того, PHP доступен почти на любом хостинге, на котором вообще доступен серверный язык.

Comment: Я согласен, что PHP легкий язык. Но мне кажется на него стоит переходить только изучив какой-нибудь строго-типизированный язык типа Си, чтобы не иметь плохих привычек потом. Вообще конечно первый язык всегда накладывает отпечаток на следующие изучаемые. Это актуально даже для С++ после Си, как утверждают знающие люди.

Answer (score 0):

Могу сказать, что на одном Вы точно не остановитесь, 101% уверенности.

JavaScript - это не столько язык программирования по специальности, сколько обычный и необходимый инструмент, который знать нужно обязательно (в прочем как и html/css).

Лично я начал, как большинство говорят с "гавноязыка" - PHP, сейчас же изучаю python, c/c++ и на этом останавливаться желания - нет. На счет PHP, то это очень, очень замурыженная тема, что в нем низкий порог вхождения и что его учат только школьники и прочее, прочее, но такое мнения появляется лишь из-за того, что в интернете очень много его выкидышей (продуктов) низкого качества, а писать что-то стоящие и качественное Вам никто не запрещает.

Answer (score -1):

python однозначно не для веба

Еще есть ruby on rails на котором очень просто писать веб приложения.
Но если у тебя Windows, то будет сложновато его запустить, он все таки для обладателей Linux или для Mac OS.

Для любого проекта подойдет php.
perl не уходит, просто он громоздок и не удобен.

Начинай с php, там все очень похоже с javascript только перед всеми переменными стоит знак $.

Вот книги, которые нужно обязательно прочитать:

- [Разработка веб-приложений с помощью PHP и MySQL](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4538872/);
- [HTML, JavaScript, PHP и MySQL. Джентльменский набор Web-мастера](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5021607/);
- [PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5648968/);
- [JavaScript. Шаблоны](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6287517/);
- [Поисковая оптимизация на PHP для профессионалов. Руководство разработчика по SEO](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3771776/);
- [Гибкая разработка веб-приложений в среде Rails](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/8153111/);
- [Язык программирования Ruby](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5704300/);
- [Программирование на Perl](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/147137/);
- [Разработка Web-сайтов с помощью Perl и MySQL](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4289407/).

Comment: кстати посмотри вакансии по ruby может заинересует
на руби написан твиттер, но сейчас как бы общество рубистов
сформировалось и нужно хорошенько подумать прежде чем его учить

мне лично нравится perl и php вместе

не забудь кстати про smarty

пример из жизни:

проект написаный на php + smarty
но фоновые действия по cron (по таймеру на сервере) выполняются на perl

но все это можно було бы написать на одном руби он рэилс и не учить кучу языков

Comment: на счет node.js - да некоторые фирмы успешно его используют, но крутого в нем ничего особо нет
просто появилась новинка и все побежали
вот только javascript в node назвать джаваскриптом трудно

Answer (score -4):

Я кстати тоже - большой любитель js.

Сейчас начал учить java - понравился. Java это старший умный брат js. Браться похожи, но есть и различия. Короче java должна понравиться.

Comment: Java не имеет ничего общего с JavaScript кроме названия

Comment: Ещё как имеет! Если вы незнакомы с java, то зачем делать такие выводы!

Comment: > Ещё как имеет! Если вы незнакомы с java, то зачем делать такие выводы!

Я знаком с Java.

JavaScript имеет гораздо больше общего с Lua, Tcl, Scheme чем с Java.

Comment: > Ещё как имеет!

Может тогда поделитесь соображениями? С-подобный синтаксис, разумеется, не в счет.

Comment: Дети мои, читайте [про JS вику][1] и плодите холивар, ибо сказано  в писании:
>  - Java реализует ООП подход, основанный на классах, JavaScript на прототипах;
 -     Java имеет статическую типизацию, JavaScript динамическую типизацию;
 -     Java загружается из скомпилированного байт-кода; JavaScript интерпретируется напрямую из файла (но часто с незаметной JIT-компиляцией).
И да прибудет с вами сила Летающего Макаронного Монстра
  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript#JavaScript_.D0.B8_Java